Chrome Print Preview is not matching actual printout
I have a web application that generates some printouts. Different printout needs different printout settings, and I have set this using CSS. So, when I change the settings, chrome shows the print preview exactly as my expected output. But when I print it, the printout does not match the preview. Why this is happening ??
BTW , I have used react in the frontend.
